# How to move layout up on keyboard focus in fullscreen activity

Tags: android, focus, android-softkeyboard

When the activity is in full screen layout, the keyboard focus is not moving the layout up to make the edit text visible.

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Have u use any scrollview inside edittext?

Comment: Please post your code @user1135999

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Set Window SoftInput Mode property to adjustPan and adjustResize

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"> </activity>
```

Other Way:

getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);

if its in 
ScrollView Try this

1) AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```

2) style.xml file ,in activity style

```
<item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> </activity>
```

Declare this in perticular activity in which you need.